# Jquery syntax equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the jquery equivalent of:

```
document.getElementById("roomType").innerHTML = $('#' + self.selectedLocation + '').html();
```

I have tried this:

```
  $('#roomType').html('#' + self.selectedLocation);
```

But I get this output:

```
#6
```

Comment: `$('#' + self.selectedLocation + '').html();` already *is* jQuery!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be:

```
$('#roomType').html( $('#' + self.selectedLocation).html() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just little something missing :

```
$('#roomType').html($('#' + self.selectedLocation).html());
```